# Packaging ROS for yocto or OpenEmbedded (using bitbake recipes)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we are interested in setting up a computing platform for our development using linux with yocto (or OpenEmbedded-Core) and the robotic operating system ROS.
We are currently at the very beginning of this development: As a first step, we want to package ROS for our own needs, but we are open to contribute this to the community if there are others that need this as well.

Has someone in the community already packaged ROS for yocto or OpenEmbedded? Are there others that also interested in a ROS package for yocto or OpenEmbedded?

We are happy about any feedback.

Lukas Bulwahn

BMW Car IT GmbH
Petuelring 116
D-80809 Muenchen
Germany

BMW Car IT GmbH
Geschäftsführer: Harald Heinecke
Sitz und Registergericht: München HRB134810

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48586/packaging-ros-for-yocto-or-openembedded-(using-bitbake-recipes)/) by [Lukas Bulwahn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3627/lukas-bulwahn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Updated answer:

Lukas has successfully achieved cross-compiling ROS documentation is here: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded

Previous Answer:

I tried about a year ago to compile barebone ROS diamondback/electric on a `Gumstix Overo` board running OpenEmbedded Linux. But it failed. I tried every method possible , cross-compiling using `oe` tools or even native compiling. I even tried to compile `apt` for `oe` then use ROS `arm` repositories, but it failed as well. I also tried using arm emulators like `qemu`. The only method that I did not try was using `eros` because of the lack of documentation back then.

I would not recommend any of above methods except [eros](http://ros.org/wiki/eros) based cross compiling to start.

For my own project, I cross-compiled a `JSON RPC` library for `oe` to export robot functionalities via `JSON RPC`. That was enough for our project. However, it is easy to wrap a ROS node (not running on the robot) over the RPC client.

Direct Method:

`Robot HW:Low Level Drivers:ROS Driver <-- Wifi --> ROS Clients`

Indirect Method

`Robot HW:Low Level Drivers:Low overhead Server <-- Wifi -->Low overhead client:ROS Driver:ROS Clients`

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1